# Measuring the similarity of 2 subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with the same upper bound.

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

The context is comparing 2 features in a DNA sequence (but the solution does not require any understanding of DNA, its features, or any kind of knowledge in biology).

For example, if a DNA sequence consists of 100 nucleotides (whatever a nucleotide might be), feature A might cover nucleotides [2-7, 17-32, 50-52, 54-57, 60-90] and feature B might cover [10-15, 49-56, 76-98]. Now, we can take each feature as simply a subset of [1-100], and forget that we are talking about DNA.

Finally, by similarity we mean any measure that might show some correlation between the features, perhaps indicating some kind of causation relation. The measure should tend to 0 when we take random subsets, and max out when the subsets are identical.

Comment: The topic of DNA correlations is quite vast. It would help if you could elaborate on what exactly you want to ultimately measure, because there are plenty of ways to define such correlations, but it's not clear which if any are truly useful.

Comment: @AlexR. In one hand, there are so called CpG islands, stretches of DNA where there is a certain pattern of repetitions of a given dinucleotide (CpG). On the other, sequences of DNA are published annotated with features, which consist in stretches of DNA which are functionally determined (e.g., genes). So the idea is to search published DNA sequences for patterns of repetitions of small polynucleotides (e.g., stretches of DNA in which ATT is repeated roughly every 100 nucleotides), and check for some correlation with functional features. So I think it should be best to abstract away DNA.

Comment: @AlexR. To complete my previous comment, "I think it should be best to abstract away DNA", because any correlation would provide a reason to study possible biological explanations for it. We are not coming from a biological theory for which we seek evidence; we instead look for a mathematical reason to look for a biological explanation.

Comment: It's fine to abstract away the DNA piece, however, I think we're still lacking a clear idea on what exactly to measure here. To define any sort of (causal) correlations (or more simply, probabilities), you need to specify a precise mathematical relation. In your $A,B$ example, what would you like $A$ to predict? For example you could study P(B | A[0:n]), e.g. the probability of observing B given the first n elements of $A$. Or you could study $P(B[i] | A[j])$. The answer to this probably highly dependent on the structure of DNA and their subsequent usefulness to you.

Comment: What about thinking purely in terms of sets? i.e., looking at some combination of the cardinality of A, B and their superset, the cardinality of the intersection between A and B, and the cardinality of their complements?